# Get the text of the current node only

Tags: cheerio

In Cheerio, how do you get just the text of the current node only?

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio')

const htmlString = '<div>hello<span>world</span></div>'

$ = cheerio.load(htmlString, { ignoreWhitespace: true })

console.log($('div').text())  //helloworld
console.log($('span').text())  //world
```

How do you get just `hello`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do this:

```
console.log($('div').contents().first().text()) # hello
```

Comment: What is it wasn't the `first()`? What if it was the 23rd?