# How to collect only the second text value of data returned from an XPATH using CheerioGS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, cheerio

The sitemap (https://futebolnatv.com.br/jogos-hoje/) looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-01">
<div class="col-md-12">
     <span class="label label-default">0</span>
     <img src="https://futebolnatv.com.br/static/times/ba92f23d6f11341548d808a0ec309acc.png" width="25" height="25">
     "Holstein Kiel"
</div>
```

Using `CheerioGS`, to collect the text value I use this path:

```
    let elements_2 = $('tbody > tr > td > div:nth-child(2)')
    elements_2.each((index, value) => {
      sheet.getRange(index+1, 3).setValue($(value).text().trim())
    })
```

But instead of just the name `Holstein Kiel`, it's coming with this number that's inserted into `<span>` that I don't want:

```
0
Holstein Kiel
```

The expected return is:

```
Holstein Kiel
```

What should I change to resolve this issue?

CheerioGS project:
https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the text of the current node only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235516/get-the-text-of-the-current-node-only)

Comment: Hi @Kos , I looked at this question before asking mine, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem, anyway thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your selector from

`$(value).text().trim()`

to

`$(value).contents().last().text().trim()`

Explanation: instead of retrieving text of whole matched element, you need to get all its nodes first (via `contents()`), then get text node you need (via `last()`). Rest of code is unchanged.

---

Reference:

- https://cheerio.js.org/docs/api/classes/Cheerio#contents
- https://cheerio.js.org/docs/api/classes/Cheerio#last

Comment: Hi @Kos , Thank you for helping me. If you are interested, I have another published question also related to the subject, thanks in advance for your attention! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71189703/how-to-protect-the-positions-to-place-the-data-in-the-worksheet-when-some-values

Answer (score 0):

You could also just delete those, sometimes that's faster:
$('.label').remove()