# How to protect the positions to place the data in the worksheet when some values are not retrieved?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cheerio

I'm using the `CheerioGS` library:

ID → `1ReeQ6WO8kKNxoaA_O0XEQ589cIrRvEBA9qcWpNqdOP17i47u6N9M5Xh0`
Project → https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs

My full code (I added it in its entirety so that they can use it in tests):

```
function importdataweb() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Page_One');
    sheet.getRange('A1:Z' + sheet.getMaxRows()).clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    const url = 'http://www.futebolnatv.com.br/jogos-hoje/';
    const contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    const $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);
  
    let elements = $('tbody > tr > th > h4 > b')
    elements.each((index, value) => {
      sheet.getRange(index+1, 1).setValue($(value).text().trim())
    })
    
    let elements_1 = $('tbody > tr > td > div:nth-child(1)')
    elements_1.each((index, value) => {
      sheet.getRange(index+1, 2).setValue($(value).text().trim())
    })
    
    let elements_2 = $('tbody > tr > td > div:nth-child(2)')
    elements_2.each((index, value) => {
      sheet.getRange(index+1, 3).setValue($(value).contents().last().text().trim())
    })
    
    let elements_3 = $('tbody > tr > td > div:nth-child(3)')
    elements_3.each((index, value) => {
      sheet.getRange(index+1, 4).setValue($(value).contents().last().text().trim())
    })
    
    let elements_4 = $('tbody > tr > td b:nth-child(2)')
    elements_4.each((index, value) => {
      sheet.getRange(index+1, 5).setValue($(value).text().trim())
    })
}
```

The result is:
[image]

Some values in the last column for some reason are not collected, so the position of some of these values in the worksheet is in the wrong place.

For example: If the first value is not collected but the second is, the second will be in row 1 of the column, then it would be wrong.

How could I add a dash `-` in the lines that the value is not collected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let data = [];

let rows = $('tbody > tr');
rows.each((i, row) => {
  const newDataRow = [
    $(row).find('th > h4 > b').text().trim(),
    $(row).find('td > div:nth-child(1)').text().trim(),
    $(row).find('td > div:nth-child(2)').contents().last().text().trim(),
    $(row).find('td > div:nth-child(3)').contents().last().text().trim(),
    $(row).find('td b:nth-child(2)').text().trim(),

  ];
  data.push(newDataRow);
});

// fill empty values
data = data.map(row => row.map(el => el ? el : '-'));


// write values to sheet
const startRow = 1;
const startCol = 1;
const numRows = data.length;
const numCols = data[0].length;

sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols).setValues(data);
```

Changes made for part after you load Cheerio object:

1. You need to collect all data, and only then write it (`setValues`) back to sheet in 1 request, to reduce script execution time and improve performance.
2. You need to loop rows (`let rows = $('tbody > tr')`) with Cheerio, to be able to combine values you need for each row so it can be displayed as a row in a spreadsheet.

Second change is more important, as it gives you ability to work with your data per row basis later, like sort, filter etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Range.setValue` for filling cell by cell one column at a time, build an Array of Array of values, then add all the values at once by using `Range.setValues`.

In order to do this, instead of grabbing one cell (`td`) from all tables (`tbody`) at once, grab the whole table (`tbody`) and check if the required cell / content exists , if not add an empty string (`''`) to the corresponding position in the Array that is being build.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You want to iterate those tr's. This will give a 2d array (untested)

```
$('tr').get().map(tr => $(tr).find("h4,.col-md-12").get().map(el => $(el).text()))
```